# How to change the user-agent string in Excel webkit?

Tags: excel, macos, office365, office-js

The user-agent string from the excel 365 webkit is set as "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/602.4.8 (KHTML, like Gecko)". I want to modify it so that it can be spoofed to be Safari browser.
I want to set it as "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/602.4.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.3 Safari/602.4.8".
Is there a way to do this in mac?

Comment: This isn't supported.

Comment: Thanks for the info, @MarcLaFleur-Microsoft.  Can you please add this info as an Answer (so that this item will show as an "Answered" question in the search results, making others more likely to benefit from the info in the future)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported. I recommend visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and adding your suggestion.